# Can we Reject/Accept specific endpoint on Jetty connector?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

we have a connector on port 7777 and we want to reject any requests that are coming for `/serverStatus` on that connector?

at the same time I want to accept only `/serverStatus` requests on a different connector which is on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Name your ServerConnectors.

The ServerConnector on port 7777 is named "admin"
The ServerConnector on port 80 is named "normal"

Then setup the webapp for `/serverStatus` to have a virtualhost of `@admin`, and your root webapp on a virtualhost of `@normal`.

See [Embedded-Jetty Cookbook: ConnectorSpecificContexts.java](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/ConnectorSpecificContexts.java) for example.

```java
package org.eclipse.jetty.cookbook;

import org.eclipse.jetty.cookbook.handlers.HelloHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection;

public class ConnectorSpecificContexts
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server();

        ServerConnector connectorA = new ServerConnector(server);
        connectorA.setPort(8080);
        connectorA.setName("connA");
        ServerConnector connectorB = new ServerConnector(server);
        connectorB.setPort(9090);
        connectorB.setName("connB");

        server.addConnector(connectorA);
        server.addConnector(connectorB);

        // Collection of Contexts
        ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
        server.setHandler(contexts);

        // Hello Handler (connection A)
        ContextHandler ctxHelloA = new ContextHandler();
        ctxHelloA.setContextPath("/");
        ctxHelloA.setHandler(new HelloHandler("Hello Connection A"));
        ctxHelloA.setVirtualHosts(new String[] { "@connA" });
        contexts.addHandler(ctxHelloA);

        // Hello Handler (connection B)
        ContextHandler ctxHelloB = new ContextHandler();
        ctxHelloB.setContextPath("/");
        ctxHelloB.setHandler(new HelloHandler("Greetings from Connection B"));
        ctxHelloB.setVirtualHosts(new String[] { "@connB" });
        contexts.addHandler(ctxHelloB);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```