# How to set a different session cookie name for every connector?

Tags: session, servlets, cookies, jetty, session-cookies

Currently I set the session cookie name in an embedded Jetty via the follow code:

```
ServletContextHandler handler = new ServletContextHandler( ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS );
handler.setInitParameter( SessionHandler.__SessionCookieProperty, "SESSIONID" + port );
setHandler( handler );
```

But then all connectors use the same session cookie name. But I want different session cookie names on different connectors.

The cause of my problem is that

- I have HTTP and HTTPS connectors
- for a HTTPS connection a `secure` session cookie is send
- It is not possible to override a `secure` cookie with an HTTP connection in the most browsers.
- After a secure cookie from a HTTPS connection it is not possible to work on a HTTP connection anymore until all browser tabs are closed. Some peoples does not close it for weeks. The server send repeatedly new session cookies but the browser does not save it.
- I can restart the server, remove the HTTPS connector. All will not work until a browser restart.

A simple fix would be to set different session cookies for different ports or for different protocols. Is this possible for with Jetty?

Comment: To the same ServletContext? or different ServletContext?

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 ServletContext in one Jetty?

Comment: Of course, that's pretty common actually.  (example: have 2 webapps, or WebAppContext's)

Comment: Calling multiple time setHandler() override the previous value. Using a ContextHandlerCollection it is not possible to add multiple ServletContexts with the same path. My context path is "/". It make also no sense because there is no binding to a single connector.

Comment: You can bind specific webapps to specific connectors using the connector name and virtualhost configuration, see past answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149232/775715

Comment: If you want the webapps to be on the same context-path, look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65116656/775715

Comment: Note that WebAppContext implements ContextHandler, so you don't have to wrap your WebAppContext in yet another ContextHandler, just use the WebAppContext directly.

Comment: Thanks this is the solution. With connector.setName() and handler.setVirtualHosts() I can solve it.